# Как выровнять текст так, чтобы не было отступов справа и слева?

Tags: html, css3

Мне нужен результат как в первой картинке. А то что получается у меня во второй картинке. Выровнять текст так чтобы не было отступов справа и слева. Вроде делаю `text-align: justify;` но получается между словами большой разрыв.
[image: Картинка 1]
[image: Картинка 2]

Comment: Тут есть встроенный аналог сниппетов, на которых можно продемонстрировать, что у вас сейчас получилось.

Comment: Погуглил немного. Судя по виду, у вас выравнивание center, а не justify. Может быть, оно где-нибудь переопределяется?

Comment: Просто в примере подобрали слова правильно и не видно разрывов больших, так как ширина строчек получилась более или менее одинаковой. Используя justify вы будете увеличивать отступы между словами. Других вариантов на css скорее всего нет.